# FreeRADIUS - Use different pipeline for different clients

Tags: radius, freeradius

I currently have a FreeRADIUS setup using EAP-TTLS.

I'd like to set it up such that requests coming from localhost use PAP, but that other requests still use EAP-TTLS.

How do I select authentication method used on a per-client basis?

Comment: There's no EAP-PAP.  Do you just mean PAP?

Comment: Oops. Got carried away typing EAP. Yeah. I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `%{client:}` expansion to query attributes of the client where the request originated.

```
authorize {
    if ("%{client:shortname}" == 'localhost') {
        pap
    } else {
        eap
    }
}
```

Adding the above snippet would result in the pap module being called if the client was configured with a shortname of 'localhost', otherwise the eap module would be called.

You can actually place arbitrary attributes in a client section and reference them with the client expansion i.e.

```
client my_client {
    ipaddr = 127.0.0.1
    foo = 'bar'
}

"%{client:foo}" # Which would expand to "bar"
```